# how to remove ":" and "," and "':" from array of strings?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have quite a basic question and I'm new to strings.
In my code I have a large array of words that contain mostly letters that I source from the users current webpage (this is a chrome extension). Occasionally I get numbers, commas and semicolons which I want to remove from this string. How do I remove them entirely?

[image]

I have tried this in my Javascript -

```
// p is a large string and words is the array of each word from that string formed by separating each form by ' ' 

   let words = p.split(' ');
   words.forEach(word => {
      console.log(word)
      let arr = word.replace('[,]+', '')
      console.log(arr)
   })
```

Comment: Isn't it easier to replace first and then split to words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply split on space and all unwanted characters:

```js
var sentence = "the quick, brown fox; jumped (over) the fence."
var seen = {};
var result = sentence
    .split(/[ ,;\(\)\.]+/)
    .sort()
    .filter(Boolean)
    .filter((word) => {
        if(seen[word]) {
            return false;
        }
        seen[word] = 1;
        return true;
    });
console.log('result: ' + result.join(', '));
```

Console output:
`result: brown, fence, fox, jumped, over, quick, the`

Explanation:

- `.split(/[ ,;\(\)\.]+/)` - split on space and all unwanted characters
- `.sort()` - sort the array
- `.filter(Boolean)` - remove empy array items
- `.filter((word) => {...})` - filter out duplicates using a `seen` object

You did not ask for the sort and filter, but I thought this might be useful for your case.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for replacing and after replace split the string

```js
let sentence = "Foo bar, etc. and so: on. Number2";
console.log(sentence.replace(/[.,:0-9]/g, "").split(" "));
```

Comment: @AbishekKumar yes, at least a hundred if you google "regex".

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to remove all characters from the strings.

```
var word = word.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')
```

Comment: Underscore counts as `\w`, I don't think the OP wants all special characters removed, but leave the underscore.

Comment: Also, `[\W\S]` does the same thing without negation.

Comment: And finally, the `i` flag does nothing in your code.